# ClassNotFoundException in eclipse

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public void ReadXL(String Path) throws Exception
    {
        FileInputStream myStream=null;

    System.out.println("InReadxl");
    File xlFile = new File(Path);

  myStream = new FileInputStream(xlFile);
    HSSFWorkbook myWB = new HSSFWorkbook(myStream);

...........................

}
```

`HSSFWorkbook myWB = new HSSFWorkbook(myStream);` is creating
`**ClassNotFoundException**()` after adding external jar file
`"poi-3.7-20101029"`. What might be causing the problem? Please, let me know
the solution of this problem.

Comment: What is the name of the missing class ? The name of the missing class is always printed in the stacktrace. With that name, you can find the needed jar on a site like http://www.findjar.com . You probably just need in your eclipse classpath an additionnal library needed by POI. That's the reason why a packaging tool like Maven is usefull : it can deals transitively with the external jars needed by a component (worth a try in your situation maybe).

Answer (score 0):

Have you got all the required Jars on the runtime & build tabs of your plugin.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and try again. Maybe a Eclipse issue.

Have you tried to use that on another project?
Are you sure about the error stack trace. Maybe the ClassNotFound Exception is caused by another internal error.

Comment: Thanks alot for all for your response. I had solved the project build fresh project