# ClassNotFoundException despite adding to classpath and pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, apache, jar

I'm trying to use one of the Apache Commons Math3 classes in Eclipse.

Downloaded the jar, and used these instructions for adding to the build path: [ClassNotFoundException in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471683/classnotfoundexception-in-eclipse).

In addition, since the project uses Maven, I added this to the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is where I'm using the class:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.fitting.MultivariateNormalMixtureExpectationMaximization;
...
MixtureMultivariateNormalDistribution mmnd = MultivariateNormalMixtureExpectationMaximization.estimate(data, 2);
```

There are no errors at compile time, but at runtime:

```
Error text:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.fitting.MultivariateNormalMixtureExpectationMaximization
```

I know there are a couple of stackoverflow answers regarding adding jar files, I've followed several of them and they don't seem to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance!